# What would cause individual Emacs frames to freeze (but not Emacs as a whole)?

Tags: debugging, emacs, x11

I build Emacs from `master`, on Ubuntu 20.04 with i3wm. Just updated my build & am seeing the oddest problem: individual Emacs frames will freeze: no UI refresh, no response to keyboard input. Other frames are fine; `emacsclient` connects & works fine.

Since the program itself isn't hung or locked up my usual bag of tricks (`toggle-debug-on-{error,quit}`, attach `gdb`, &c) is no help. Nothing in `*Message*` or `*Warnings*`.

I'm now in the process of stripping down my "instance under test", getting it closer & closer to a plain/vanilla Emacs to see if the problem stops. It's made me realize I don't really know much about the Emacs UI implementation, so this question is not a request for debugging help so much as pointers on how Emacs services input & handles UI updates on a per-frame basis.